# JQuery numbers of cell, calculate sum in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to send, the numbers of every cell, and calculate the sum of them in php. Then show the result in text input But it did not work.How Can I do it?

This is my php code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['keyup'])){
    $sum1 = $_POST['sum1'];
    $sum2 = $_POST['sum2'];
    $sum3 = $_POST['sum3'];

    $resultado = $sum1+ $sum2 + $sum3;

     echo "Resultado: " .'<input type="text" name="resultado" value="'.$resultado.'">';

 }


?>
```

[FULL FIDDLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/2JVP5/)

Thank You in Advance

Comment: What does not work? The code looks good. Maybe `$_POST['keyup']` is empty? Edit: If you try to use the JavaScript in the jsFiddle you posted, those fields have no `name=` attribute.

Comment: @GerbenJacobs I think that is a problem with the keyup, But I dont understand what event should I send.

Comment: Works great in the fiddle ...

Comment: @Maxime did you added the PHP code?

Comment: can you show us the code for the post itself? Also (just a quick question) why are you doing this server side? You have all the figures in your js??

Comment: @GrahamRitchie What did you mean?I only want to sum all the cells of table in PHP, then send the result back and show it in a input text.

Comment: I mean that if you are simply summing the items (not needing to store them) then do it via javascript rather than on the server. As you have already summed all the rows you can just add those up. This applies even if you are storing just the total value as you would then just POST the total. Don't use a server to add things up if you dont need to store the data / manipulate it further - if you do then ignore what i said :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick look in your full code and it seem the form tags are missing.
you need to embody your code in between form tags. which will run a script.

```
<form action="yourphpfile" method="post"></form>
```

if you dont want to load a new page you need to use Ajax which is a bit more complicated.
more info about form can be found here.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

edit the action script will run when a submit input button of some sort is clicked.

second edit.
I looked into some old project to see how I instead refreshed a page with ajax which goes as follows.

```
//This function will need to be called on a button click for example
function login(){
    var sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1");
    var sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2");
    var sum3 = document.getElementById("sum3"); 
    //Do some extra refining here if needed. Depends on how the data is obtained.
    sum1 = sum1.value;
    sum2 = sum2.value;
    sum3 = sum3.value;
    //Calls the functions below
    ajax(sum1, sum2, sum3);
}

//Javascript call this function on a button click 
//or create an extra function that calls this and loads the sums from the page.
function Ajax(sum1, sum2, sum3){
    var xml;
    xml = setXML(xml);
    xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200){
            document.getElementById(DIV THAT WILL NEED TO BE UDATED HERE ).innerHTML=xml.responseText;
        }
    };
    xml.open("POST", URLTOYOURSCRIPT.php ,true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.send("sum1="+sum1+"&sum2="+sum2+"&sum3="+sum3+);
}
function setXML(xml){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return xml;
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    return xml;
    }
}
```

and then your php script will need the following.

```
//Obtains the sums from the post data send by ajax.
$sum1 = $_POST["sum1"];
$sum2 = $_POST["sum2"];
$sum3 = $_POST["sum3"];
//Perform some extra checks here like isnumeric() to see if they are actual numbers etc.
if(is_numeric($sum1) && is_numeric($sum2) && is_numeric($sum3){
    //Calculates the sum and echoes it on your existing page.
    $totalsum = $sum1+$sum2+$sum3;
    echo $totalsum;
}else{
    echo "you did not insert numbers"
}
```

Comment: I do it with ur code but didnt work, I dont know what can be the problem :/

Comment: if you're talking about ajax, you first need to change 2 things, the parts that I capitalized.( DIV THAT WILL) this is a div in your page where the result of you code will be echoed and will appear. and secondly(URLTOYOURSCRIPT.php)which will need the url to your php script. The third thing you need is an extra function that will obtain the sum data from your page(using innerhtml or something like that) which will then serve as input for my function there.

Comment: Can You make me a little example please? I dont understand it very well :/

Comment: I made an example so changing the 2 vars I told you to change and making this extra function which I gave an example of in the post now

Comment: I dont find the way to implement it in all my code.

Comment: This is javascript code so you need to put it all between <script type="text/javascript> </script> tags on your html-page or refer to an external js-file. Did you do that? and you need to add <button onclick = "login();">sum</button>

Comment: Yes, But If your see my code in Fiddle,I have to take all the cells numbers and sum all in PHP, But I dont know If im correct with that too, to Implement your code.

Comment: If I understand correctly you obtain the data from input textfields right? so with my function the extra refining that needed to be done is. sum1 = sum1.value;(etc) this obtains the value that was filled in the input field by the user.

Comment: Yes, But I dont know how collect all the data from input textfields, make a sum of it in php and then create a input text with the result.

Comment: I expanded it so now the php side is more visible too

Comment: ill be gone for some time now

Comment: OK, it give me erros :/

Comment: you need to be able to adapt this code so it works for you, and I might have made some syntax errors at certain points indeed, because I didnt not test this.